# Canvas draws over previous image Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm working on a small paint application and when I save an image it saves over the previous drawn ones even if I try to clear the canvas. You can see the image below to see the problem.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHjmH.png

canvas.delete("all") clears the canvas but the previous images are still retained. The full code is written below

```py
from tkinter import *
import PIL
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
#from model import *


def save():
    global image_number
    filename = f'image_{image_number}.jpg'   # image_number increments by 1 at every save
    image1.save(filename)
    image_number += 1
    #play_with_image()



def activate_paint(e):
    global lastx, lasty
    cv.bind('<B1-Motion>', paint)
    lastx, lasty = e.x, e.y


def paint(e):
    global lastx, lasty
    x, y = e.x, e.y
    cv.create_line((lastx, lasty, x, y), width=3)
    #  --- PIL
    draw.line((lastx, lasty, x, y), fill='black', width=3)
    lastx, lasty = x, y

def clear():
    cv.delete("all")
    #for item in cv.find_all():
    #    cv.delete(item)

root = Tk()

lastx, lasty = None, None
image_number = 0

cv = Canvas(root, width=640, height=480, bg='white')
# --- PIL
image1 = PIL.Image.new('RGB', (640, 480), 'white')
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image1)

cv.bind('<1>', activate_paint)
cv.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)

btn_save = Button(text="save", command=save)
btn_save.pack()

btn_clear = Button(text="clear", command=clear)
btn_clear.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

How can I save the new canvas without overwritting over the other ones?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't saving a canvas, you are saving an image. It doesn't matter what you do to the canvas since it's never saved.

You never change or reset the image. Your `clear` function needs to clear the image in addition to the canvas.